# Heroku Update SSL Certificates

Tags: ssl, heroku

I'm trying to update the ssl certificate for an app running on the `bamboo-ree-1.8.7` stack.

When I try to simply list the current certificates `heroku certs` I encounter the error

> The requested API endpoint was not found. Are you using the right HTTP verb (i.e. 'GET' vs.    'POST'), and did you specify your intended version with the 'Accept' header?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update to the latest [Heroku toolbelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/) version. You may be using an old version that contains a reference to a deprecated path.

Also, I'm not sure if the fact you are still using the legacy bamboo stack matters in this case.

Comment: I performed a similar change for an app on the cedar stack last week and it worked. That led me to believe the issue was related to the stack and not the tool. Thanks for your help